# Forma mais fácil de transformar requisição em FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, formdata

```js
this.getArray = function(callback){
    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "index.php?modulo=ClientesOnline&acao=getClientes",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param({ajax:1}),
    }).success(callback);
    //$http.post("index.php?modulo=ClientesOnline&acao=getClientes", {ajax:1}).success(callback);
};
```

Pessoal, o código acima foi feito por mim através de várias pesquisas.

**Minha dúvida**

Existe alguma forma mais fácil de escrever essa linha:

```js
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

Pois `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` é um pouco complicado de escrever no dia a dia. :/

Obrigado desde já! Agradeço.

Comment: Isso mesmo, existe uma forma?

Comment: Você pode deixar o texto em um arquivo ou recurso de *snippet* do IDE e colocar no código nas pouquíssimas vezes que seja necessário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode armazenar os cabeçalhos em uma variável:

```js
var headersAjax = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
```

E então, sempre que você quiser fazer uma requisição com Ajax com este cabeçalho, você usa o conteúdo da variável:

```js
this.getArray = function(callback) {
    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "index.php?modulo=ClientesOnline&acao=getClientes",
        headers: headersAjax,
        data: $.param({ajax:1}),
    }).success(callback);
};
```

Comment: Perfeito, não havia pensado em fazer isso porque estava buscando que a própria linguagem poderia haver uma forma mais fácil de escrita. Porém é uma ótima solução cara! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o uso do *$httpProvider* que é um bom lugar onde você pode definir configurações que sejam comuns a várias requisições. Usando o seu caso como exemplo, poderia ser feita dessa forma:

```
angular.module(<nomeDoModulo>).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpprovider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
}]);
```

Fazendo assim, todas as suas requisições *POST* terão seu cabeçalho de requisição modificados para este que definimos.

Para saber mais sobre este serviço, tem a documentação https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider